# Is it necessary to close the opposite ends of a pipe in parent and child?

Tags: pipe, c, ipc

The following is a **general** `pipe()` **usage** example:

```
int fd[2];
pipe(fd);

if((childpid = fork()) == -1)
{
        perror("fork");
        exit(1);
}

if(childpid == 0)
{
        /* Child process closes up input side of pipe */
        close(fd[0]);

        ////.....some code....////
        exit(0);
}
else
{
        /* Parent process closes up output side of pipe */
        close(fd[1]);

        ////.....some code....////
}
```

What I want to know is that **whether the call to** `close(fd[0])` in the child and `close(fd[1])` in the parent process **is necessary**.

**What happens if I don't** `close()` them and use only `fd[1]` in the child and `fd[0]` in the parent.

**Is it closed just so that we accidentally don't do something** with those descriptors?

Answer (score 3):

If both processes have both ends of the pipe open, if one dies, the other one will deadlock instead of detecting EOF on reading (because there's still a writer: itself) or being killed by a SIGPIPE on writing (because there's still a reader: itself).